# "Unnest_wider' but keep matching entries in the same column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame with nested lists in one column.

```
df<-data_frame(Code = c('100', '100', '101', '102', '102'),
               Type = c("Township","Township","Township","Municipality","County"),
               Name = c("Jefferson","Lake","Lake","Springfield","Washington")) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = Code, names_from=Type, values_from = Name) 

> print(df)
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  Code      Township              Municipality   County   
  <chr>     <list>                <list>         <list>   
1 100       c("Jefferson","Lake") NULL           NULL   
2 101       Lake                  NULL           NULL   
3 102       NULL                  Springfield    Washington
```

I'd like to break out the nested list, but keep entries that are the same in the same column. However, using `unnest_wider()` puts matching entries into separate columns because of the order they appear in the nested list.

```
df<-unnest_wider(df, Township, names_sep = "_")

Code  Township_1 Township_2 Municipality County   
  <chr> <chr>      <chr>      <list>       <list>   
1 100   Jefferson  Lake       NULL         NULL>   
2 101   Lake       NA         NULL         NULL>   
3 102   NA         NA         Springfield  Washington
```

But instead I'd like all same entries to appear in the same column, so here,  "Lake" would only appear in Township_1, not in both Township_1 and Township_2.

```
Code  Township_1 Township_2 Municipality County   
  <chr> <chr>      <chr>      <list>       <list>   
1 100   Lake       Jefferson  NULL         NULL>   
2 101   Lake       NA         NULL         NULL>   
3 102   NA         NA         Springfield  Washington
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this: transform the vectors of your `Township` list as factors, this way, the order should be respected.

```
library(purrr)

df %>%
  mutate(Township = purrr::map(Township, ~ factor(., levels = c('Lake', 'Jefferson'))))
```

Comment: Yes, unfortunately the actual data set has ~50,000 rows with lists of different sizes in many different columns that need to be unnested.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `unnest_longer()` and then `pivot_wider()` after. Depending on the details of your real dataset, you will probably need to tweak this. You did say they were nested in one column, which makes it more simple than if in multiple.

```r
df %>% 
  unnest_longer(Township) %>% 
  unnest_longer(Municipality) %>% 
  unnest_longer(County) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Township, names_prefix = "Township_", values_from = Township) %>% 
  relocate(Code, starts_with("Township")) %>% 
  select(-Township_NA)
```

Which gives:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 5
  Code  Township_Jefferson Township_Lake Municipality County    
  <chr> <chr>              <chr>         <chr>        <chr>     
1 100   Jefferson          Lake          NA           NA        
2 101   NA                 Lake          NA           NA        
3 102   NA                 NA            Springfield  Washington
```